# Files from OneDrive folder always open read only

Tags: windows-8, onedrive

I use Windows 8.1.

Everytime I try to open a document (Word/Excel etc) from my OneDrive folder it opens as read only. When I close Word and open it again I can edit it.

Where can I change that? Can I change that? My OneDrive is set up to make all files available offline on my PC.

Comment: Please take a look at all the "Sharing and Security" settings and ensure you Onedrive compliance to the necessary settings. Please refer the link : http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/forum/sdfiles/cant-make-changes-to-skydrive-due-to-admin-rights/2faec4e6-e923-493b-ba84-9d7ede30a977

Comment: I have tried the provided solution and so far everything works. Some users though point out that it has to be done again once in a while. Feel free to post your comment as an answer.

Comment: where is the provided solution?

Comment: In the first comment.

Comment: the first comment link does not work!

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find the solution in the link as it says access denied (same after registering to Microsoft forums with an Office 365 account)
In my case, the problem was similar but not exactly the same conditions: Onedrive for business, Office 365 and Windows server 2016. However, since I've struggled with the problem for quite a bit, I think it's better to post a solution.
For me the solution was going to security (right-click on the folder->properties->security tab), go to advanced permissions. There, I could see there were Deny permissions (specifically write and delete). I removed the deny permissions and now I can write to that folder.