# All Office 365 files open "Read Only" after activating OneDrive

Tags: onedrive

I have hundreds of Office files (Word, Excel, etc.) in the Documents folder on my laptop drive (C:).  They are all editable (i.e., none of them is designated "Read Only").  This morning I activated my OneDrive account and copied some Word and Excel files from my C: drive to the OneDrive.  After that all files on both my OneDrive and on my C: drive (including files that I did NOT copy to OneDrive) open only in Read Only mode.  If I edit a file and try to save it under a new name, I get an error message that says I don't have permission to save to the folder.  Basically I'm no longer recognized as the Administrator even though I'm the only user on the computer.  I tried reinstalling Office 365 but that didn't work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try editing the file permissions?  (Should I explain how to do this?)  I don't mean you should do this for every single file -- that would be too tedious -- I only mean for this to be part of the troubleshooting process.

Comment: Ah -- I found a similar question -- hope it helps: http://superuser.com/questions/842694/files-from-onedrive-folder-always-open-read-only

Comment: "says I don't have permission to save to the folder" -- sounds like the issue is folder permissions, not file permissions.